# Isomorphism between Picard group and a Sheaf cohomology group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I would like to know how to prove that : $ \mathrm{Pic} ( X ) \simeq H^1 ( X , \mathcal{O}_{X}^* ) $. I specially want to know how to prove that $ \mathrm{Pic} ( X ) \to H^1 ( X , \mathcal{O}_{X}^* ) $ is injective. $ X $ is a complex manifold.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check out [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/197971/39599) question. What you want is the rank one holomorphic version.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121424/picard-group-and-cohomology?rq=1.

Comment: Besides checking other questions, you might also want to provide your definition of the Picard group. It's not uncommon to _define_ it as the sheaf cohomology group, in which case there would be nothing to prove..

Comment: @Bryan You should also provide the definition of $H^1$: for Čech cohomology this is fairly straightforward, but there is some extra work to be done for derived functor cohomology.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best reference for that is the book by Griffiths and Harris "Principles of algebraic geometry", the chapter about divisors and line bundles.